# Global denial of certain file(s) on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, deny

I run a webserver under Apache with several virtual hosts. I would like to prohobit the access to certain file names, but instead of using a deny rule on each vh I would like to know if I can achieve this with global configuration?

#### Update

I found the following to suit my needs.

```
<FilesMatch "myfile.ext">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I'm not certain you cannot (you can try it), but even if you can it will be highly unusual. Instead, you could use `include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

> Configuration directives set in the main server context (outside any `<VirtualHost>` container) will be used only if they are not overridden by the virtual host settings.

So in theory setting directives in the main config, if allowed by the [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) of the directive, should work and be enforced as long as you don't override the directive in either the `<VirtualHost>` section and prohibit `.htaccess` overrides.

But it is a simple case of testing if things actually work as expected...

Comment: Thank you very much HBrujin! Ofcourse .htaccess is a restricted file so I just copied that part to fit my needs :)